# The right word for search with looking over something in cursory way

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-request, vocabulary, writing

I am trying to write but stumbling to find a word for the following situation. Here is line what i wrote

> And one more hidden reason I found that is the greed to store these
>   beauty of right now life as a perfect part of the picture, so that
>   someday if I **fumble** the picture of life what past painted

I used word fumble but I feel it is not the perfect word to say that if **I look back on the picture, look back with a cursory search for some colors that are perfect to give bliss or say to feel some past again.** I want some aesthetic and more perfect word. I looked over dictionary but the synonyms makes me feel more that I used some less perfect word. Please help me. 
Please point out any other mistakes, grammar etc., too.

Comment: I think a word you might consider is [_peruse_](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22peruse+through+pictures%22). That said, the sentence needs a **LOT** of work.

Comment: I thought maybe reminisce - but for sure the rest of the sentence needs a lot of work; currently I'm not even quite certain what the overall intended meaning is.

Comment: The biggest problem with your sentence right now is grammar, not vocabulary. I can't work out what you're actually trying to say with it. :-(

Comment: Same here... I really found it hard even to comment on this! @DavidRicherby

Comment: Please look at the complete paras I still feel that is a big need to work on sentence structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has the earmarks of a bilingual dictionary that lacks nuance:

hidden reason = motive ?

greed = desire?

life right now = the present moment?

Since you use the words "fumble" and "stumble", I'm guessing that you might be searching for the word "flip".

To *fumble through* the contents of a desk drawer, say, means to look there hastily for something, moving items this way and that in the hope of finding the object.

When photographs were printed on paper, we might have said "Some day, as you are *flipping through* these pictures, you might find one that brings a long forgotten moment back to you."

To *flip through* a set of pictures meant to look through the set somewhat aimlessly, just to see what images the set holds.

*Flipping through* might still work even if the photographs are on a mobile phone.

EDIT:

Based on additional comments:  You could *let your eyes  wander* over the picture.

Comment: no here i mean a big picture a single one and i m looking over its parts like if it is a larger than wall or something like that, else all what you guessed as meanings are what i used them to reflect. Please look at the question back i have added full para

Comment: If I understand you right, you are allowing your eyes to rest upon different sections of a very large picture, almost at random?

Comment: exactly like if i m searching random for which is most beautiful part that i can stare

Comment: Please see addendum in answer.

Comment: if i use scour you feel it is a word for such situation ?

Comment: I wouldn't say "I *scoured* the vast painting looking for those areas with the most beautiful details."  I would use scour like this: "The soldier scoured the valley below, looking for camouflaged machine-gun nests."